# WPF: Exception when Binding to an ObservableCollection that has been filled asynchronously

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, observablecollection

I´m having a problem adding items to an ObservableCollection that is created in a background thread via async await. I´m binding MenuItemViewModels to a hierarchical datatemplate in a TreeView ContextMenu that are loaded dynamically in a ViewModel written for the Treeview (TreeNodesViewModel -> LoadMenuItemsAsync; UI-Thread):

```
public class TreeNodesViewModel: BaseViewModel {
    private FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel> menuitems = new FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel>();
    private CollectionViewSource viewsourcemenuitems = new CollectionViewSource();

    public FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel> MenuItems {
        get { return menuitems; }
        set { SetProperty(ref menuitems, value); }
    }

    public TreeNodesViewModel() {
        GenerateCompleteTree();
    }

    public void GenerateCompleteTree(bool setSelectLastSelectedItem = true, string path = null) {
        LoadMenuItemsAsync();
        ...
    }

    public async void LoadMenuItemsAsync() {
        Task load = Task.Run(async () => {
            foreach (Type type in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsClass && x.BaseType == typeof(MenuItemBaseViewModel) && x.Namespace.Equals("***.UI.Tree.MenuItems"))) {
                MenuItems.Add((MenuItemBaseViewModel)Activator.CreateInstance(type));
            }
        });

        await load;
    }
}
```

Each MenuItemViewModel derives from a MenuItemBaseViewModel that also contains an ObservableCollection SubItems in order to create a Hierarchical Menustructure with an HierachicalDataTemplate:

```
public class MenuItemAddNewSystem : MenuItemBaseViewModel {

    public MenuItemAddNewSystem() : base(PackIconModernKind.Add, Colors.Green) {
        Uid = "...";
        Header = "Add new System";
    }

    #region Overrides
    public override bool IsVisible {
        get {
            return true;
        }
    }


    public override void ExecuteMouseLeftButtonDownCommand(object parameter) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}


public abstract class MenuItemBaseViewModel : BaseViewModel {
    private FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel> subitems = new FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel>();
    private CollectionViewSource viewsource = new CollectionViewSource();

    public FullyObservableCollection<MenuItemBaseViewModel> SubItems {
        get { return subitems; }
        set { if (SetProperty(ref subitems, value)) OnPropertyChanged("MenuItemSource"); }
    }

    public ICollectionView MenuItemSource {
        get {
            if (SubItems.Count(x => x.IsVisible) == 0) return null;
            viewsource.Source = SubItems.Where(x => x.IsVisible); //<--- Exception here!
            return viewsource.View;
        }
    }

    public MenuItemBaseViewModel(Enum packiconkind, Color? iconcolor = null) {
        SetPackIcon(packiconkind, iconcolor);
        AddEventHandler(SubItems);
        ...
    }

    #region NotifyChanged-Events
    public override void NotifyCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        OnPropertyChanged("MenuItemSource");
    }

    public override void NotifyItemPropertyChanged(object sender, ItemPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("IsVisible")) OnPropertyChanged("MenuItemSource");
    }
    #endregion

    ...
}
```

XAML:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="MenuItemContextMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, Path=TreeViewModel.MenuItemSource}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MenuItemBaseViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuItemSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTip}"/>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding MouseLeftButtonDownCommand}"/>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

My problem is, that loading the MenuItems via async await gives me an exception when updating the MenuItemSource in the MenuItemBaseViewModel via NotifyPropertyChanged:

> **System.InvalidOperationException:** 
>   The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

(see comment in code)

Binding the ContextMenu to the MenuItems-Collection in the TreeNodesViewModel does not give an exception as the Collection is created on UI-Thread, but binding to the 2nd hierarchical layer SubItems in MenuItemBaseViewModel throws an exception.
I´ve tried the following options:

- Using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization and locking during add or remove operations
- using Application.Current.Dispatcher
- using viewsource.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
- using Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke

Nothing works and I keep getting the error.
I also tried implementing an AsyncObservableCollection (https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/04/17/wpf-binding-to-an-asynchronous-collection/) without success. Can Anyone help me out on this one?

Comment: The Tooltip for the downvote button states, that "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I don´t think any of this is applicable here. Even if something is unclear - why not ask me to clarify then? It is quite apparent that I´ve gone to some effort formulating the question and also have been researching without finding an answer before I posted this. Not the first time this has happened - leaving me with a negative vote on a perfectly valid question in my opinion.

Comment: CollectionViewSource is a DependencyObject meaning it is bound to the thread on which it is created. You are creating these menu item view models on a background thread so that is the thread on which they must be used. Perhaps you could do all the filtering on a background thread and then create them on the UI thread. Or another possibility it to dispense with the view source in the view model altogether and bind the source to SubItems and menu item visibility to the IsVisible property (with suitable converter).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! I wasnt aware of the fact that it might be the ICollectionView causing the problem. I altered the code of the MenuItemSource Getter like this: "public ICollectionView MenuItemSource { get { return new CollectionViewSource { Source = SubItems.Where(x => x.IsVisible) }.View; } }" and now all is fine :-) Post an answer if you like and I´ll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Mike Zboray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517852/mike-zboray) stated in the comments, the ICollectionView needs to be created in the correct thread. Changing the the getter of the ICollectionView in the MenuItemBaseViewModel fixed the problem as the previous ICollectionView had been created in a background thread. Returning a newly created one fixes the issue for me:

```
public ICollectionView MenuItemSource {
    get { return new CollectionViewSource { Source = SubItems.Where(x => x.IsVisible) }.View; }
}
```